# How can I find the text of a text box using VBA with Win32 functions?

Tags: vba, winapi, textbox, gettext

I am trying to get the text from a textbox from a program using VBA.  I am using Win32 programming and capturing the handles and trying to send messages using constants.  I have simplified the code I am using and put it below.

The part I am having trouble with is with the WM_GETTEXT message.  That line code crashes the program after a few seconds of being run.

Based on my research, ThunderRT6 means the target program was made with VB 6.

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindow Lib "user32.dll" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long

Private Declare PtrSafe FindWindowEx Lib "user32.dll" Alias "FindWindowExA" (ByVal hWnd1 As Long, ByVal hWnd2 As Long, ByVal lpsz1 As String, ByVal lpsz2 As String) As Long

Private Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32.dll" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, ByRef lParam As Any) As Long

Private Const WM_GETTEXT As Long = &HD
Private Const WM_GETTEXTLENGTH As Long = &HE


Sub GetTextFromTextBox()
Dim hwnd As Long, myTxtBox As Long
  hwnd = FindWindow(vbNullString, "My Window")
  myTxtBox = FindWindowEx(hwnd, 0&, "ThunderRT6TextBox", vbNullString)

Dim myBuffer As String
Dim myPtr As Long
  myPtr = VarPtr(myBuffer)
Dim myLen As Long
  myLen = SendMessage(myTxtBox, WM_GETTEXTLENGTH, 0, ByVal 0&)
  Debug.Print SendMessage(myTxtBox, WM_GETTEXT, myLen, ByVal myPtr)
End Sub
```

Comment: Use [UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32) instead. If nothing else, at least you aren't running into the `WM_GETTEXTLENGTH` [TOCTOU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-of-check_to_time-of-use) race.

Comment: I can't.  I'm on my work computer and I can only use default programs including Excel.  I have a program that shows all handles being used and provides the coordinates and I also have a program that shows what pointers the mouse cursor are on.  That's all I have to work with.

Comment: I mean what coordinates the mouse cursor point to

Comment: You need to allocate space for SendMessage to actually return the string. So add something like `myBuffer = Space(myLen + 1)` after myLen contains the length of the str. And just pass myBuffer byval in your WM_GETTEXT SendMessage call. `Debug.Print SendMessage(myTxtBox, WM_GETTEXT, myLen, ByVal myBuffer)`

Comment: I'm using option explicit.  What should I  dim myBuffer as?

Comment: Leave it the way you have it. `dim myBuffer as String` Edit: keep in mind String in vba means a BSTR so a cch followed by a pointer to the actual unicode string. So the ByVal of the string is just the value of that pointer. Which is basically, not considering the silent unicode conversion, what the win32 api expects. https://flylib.com/books/en/4.460.1.9/1/

Comment: *"I can't."* - UI Automation is a system service. If you can use Win32 API calls then you can use UI Automation.

Comment: @cburn11 That works almost perfectly, but the value put in myBuffer is short by 1 character.  I was reading in the link you provided that the string is preceded by a length value.  for that reason should I do myBuffer = Space(myLen + 2)?  Or is there something else going on here? Edit: I just made the above changes and the result is the same.  Short by 1 character.

Comment: I messed that up. `myBuffer = Space(myLen)` and `SendMessage(myTxtBox, WM_GETTEXT, myLen + 1, ByVal myBuffer)` should work.

Comment: Add `Dim myRet as Long` and change the SendMessage call to: `myRet = SendMessage(myTxtBox, WM_GETTEXT, myLen + 1, ByVal myBufffer)` when you step through the code, after the SendMessage call  does myRet should myLen?. WM_GETTEXT seems to want the total size of the buffer passed, including the null termination, but returns the cch actually written.

Comment: If it helps, this is your slightly modified code that isn't off by 1: https://i.imgur.com/YLNCsfX.png

Comment: Everything works perfectly now.  Thank you for your help!